# Uploading files with asp.net core into database as byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My code:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public byte[] AvatarImage { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeVm
    {
      public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
      public string FullName { get; set; }
      public IFormFile AvatarImage { get; set; }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeVm model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var employees = new Employee
            {
               FullName  = model.FullName
            };
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                employees.AvatarImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
                await model.AvatarImage.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

            }
            _context.Add(employees);
               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

All i got was

> nullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. await model.AvatarImage.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

I'm new to asp.net core, I don't understand how asp.net core handles `MemoryStream`.

Comment: You need to figure out which specific piece is null, `model` or `AvatarImage`. This has nothing to do with the memory stream, it is not even getting that far, you need to find out why your source object is null first. (Also you need to swap the order, `employees.AvatarImage = memoryStream.ToArray();` needs to be after `await model.AvatarImage.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);`, however you could just do `employees.AvatarImage = model.AvatarImage` and not need the memory stream at all.)

Answer (score 9):

You have to store IFormFile content to the memorystream before. The memory stream object is empty so calling it `memoryStream.ToArray()` is what brings the null value. Assign the uploaded avatar to it first before calling the method above.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
     await model.AvatarImage.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
     employees.AvatarImage = memoryStream.ToArray();

}
```